# Making errors in a simple problem on right triangles

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

I have the following figure:

[image]

Let's consider two right triangles, with right angles at points $L$ and $M$, respectively. Since the lines passing through points $A$ and $C$ and through points $L$ and $M$ are parallel, intersected by a transversal passing through points $A$ and $L$, alternate interior angles are equal. Therefore, triangles ALC and AML are similar, hence we have $\frac{LM}{AM}=\frac{AL}{LC}$. Consequently, $\frac{LM}{AM}$ is known to be $k\in\mathbb R$ and the side $LC$ is known to be $a\in\mathbb R$, while the unknown is the hypotenuse $AC$. A straightforward calculation yields $AC=a\sqrt{k^2+1}$.

Initially, making an error, I had erroneously deduced from the first equality that $AL=k$ instead of $AL=k\cdot a$, which sparked a small curiosity. I wonder, how should the above diagram be modified to have $AL=k$, and thus $AC=\sqrt{k^2+a^2}$? I'm struggling to visualize the modified figure, but perhaps this question lacks interest or is poorly framed? What are your thoughts?

Comment: $AL=k$ just implies $a=1$.

Comment: I meant $a\neq 1$, sorry

Comment: Then you might need to change other conditions. I guess you meant $\Delta{ALC}$ and $\Delta{LMA}$ are similar.

Comment: "Since the lines passing through points A and C and through points L and M are parallel": says who?

Comment: Adding a ratio with a length can be meaningful only if a unit length is somehow introduced. "How should the above diagram modified" is a bit vague: of course you could completely change the meaning of $AC$, $k$ and $a$ to get your result.

Comment: You can move the point C along the ray LC. The acute angles of the upper triangle will change, but all the right angles will stay. So there is no similarity of triangles.